# getting IndexOutOfBoundException : Invalid array range 0 to 0 , So context = null, So App crashes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, interstitial

working on InterstitialAd excercise, **onClick** of a button, calling tellJoke(). tellJoke() calls a AsyncTask . 
In AsyncTask, **params size is 0 , getting IndexOutOfBundException, so context is null.**

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after setting activity main");

}

 public static void tellJoke(View view){          
    new EndpointsAsyncTask().execute();
 }
}
```

**MainActivityFragment.java**

```
 public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

  InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

  public MainActivityFragment() {
  }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) root.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    //interstitialAd part starts here
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
            MainActivity.tellJoke(getView());
        }
    });
    return root;
}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
 }
}
```

**EndpointsAsyncTask.java**

```
public class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, String> {

private static String LOG_TAG = EndpointsAsyncTask.class.getSimpleName();

private static MyApi myApiService = null;
private Context context ;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {

    if(myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
        MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
            .setRootUrl("https://build-it-bigger.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
        // end options for devappserver
        myApiService = builder.build();
    }       

    if (params != null) {
        context = params[0];
    }
    try {            
        return myApiService.fetchJoke().execute().getData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {        
    if (context != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, JokeDisplayActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, result);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}}
```

please help, where am i doing wrong ? and please suggest if other way to do this.

Comment: params size is 0 because you don't pass any parameter...

Comment: @njzk2 thanks. where do i need to pass parameter ? please guide

Comment: if I do like this - new EndpointsAsyncTask().execute(this); after removing static keyword from tellJoke() , then facing problem in MainActivityFrangement , stating "Non - static method can't be referenced from static context. please guide here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide the parameter for your AsyncTask when you're calling `execute` (also remove static):

```
public void tellJoke(View view){          
   new EndpointsAsyncTask().execute(getActivity());
}
```

`this` refers to the activity and thus implements the `Context` interface (if called from an activity).

**EDIT**:
Move your `tellJoke` method to the Fragment and call it like this:

```
tellJoke();
```

Notice that now you do not pass `this` but rather `getActivity()` since you're in a Fragment.

Comment: thanks but if I am passing this then I have to remove static keyword. If I remove that also then facing problem in MainActivityFragment stating  - "Non -static can't be reference from static context". please help.

Comment: ...now I am getting this error & app crashes again - "Could not find method tellJoke(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class" I am calling tellJoke in onClick xml only.

Comment: Well just add on click listener in java code on your button. It's very easy. And in it call the `tellJoke`.

Comment: thank you so much. Now app is working fine but mInterstitialAd is not showing. please guide me here.

Comment: No problem at all. Consider accepting the answer if it fixed your **original** problem. As for the ad not showing, that's a completely different thing, try googling a bit or posting a **new** question if you cannot manage to fix it yourself please... Best regards, Enjoy coding!

Comment: ..I have already accepted. Since I am a new member, I am not having enough reputations. as soon as I will get enough reputaion it will reflect . for that you can also mark this question as upvote so that i can get some reputaion/batches. thanks

Comment: Ah, you mean that you **upvoted**. Thanks for that as well. You can **accept** the answer since it's your question by clicking a tick mark next to my answer. That's not the same as the upvote :)